# Problem with PHP shortcode cutting wordpress title

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, title

I have tinkered a small PHP code that automatically outputs all posts of the currently displayed category to me via shortcode (except the currently displayed post). So far so good, now my titles are always built the same way "87 lorem ipsum - lorem ipsum". The code now cuts away the number as intended, but not the text behind the "-".

Website is: [sprueche-fuer-dich.de](https://sprueche-fuer-dich.de/)

Code:

```
function show_cat_posts_func( $atts ) {
global $post;

$url_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$url_segments = explode('/', trim($url_path, '/'));
$category_from_url = isset($url_segments[0]) ? $url_segments[0] : '';

$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => $category_from_url, 
), $atts );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => $a['category'],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'post__not_in' => isset($post) ? array($post->ID) : array(),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$output = '';
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    $output .= '<p class="sidebar-heading-txt">' . $a['category'] . '</p>';

    $output .= '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $title = substr($title, 3);
        $title = explode('–', $title)[0];
        $output .= '<li class="sidebar-small-txt"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
} else {
    $output .= '<p>Keine Beiträge in dieser Kategorie gefunden.</p>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();

return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_cat_posts', 'show_cat_posts_func' );'
```

Comment: I can't tell what the actual problem is supposed to be, resp. what exactly you actually want now? Your code, applied to a title value of `87 lorem ipsum - lorem ipsum`, should result in `lorem ipsum ` - so what exactly did you want instead now? (Using an example that does not use the same phrase in _two_ places, might perhaps be helpful.)

Comment: Sure! Please see: https://sprueche-fuer-dich.de/geburtstag/sprueche-zum-60-geburtstag/. In the sidebar there are some posts. Originally they look something like "58 Sprüche zum 18. Geburtstag – schöne, coole & mehr". Now the code is stripped and shown as "Sprüche zum 18. Geburtstag – schöne, coole & mehr". But it should be "Sprüche zum 18. Geburtstag". So I want to erase all text behind "–".

Comment: In that particular title, you do not have a normal "minus" `-` in there, but what looks like an en dash, `–`.

Comment: Changed the above code as well as my in the functions.php. Unfortunately still not working

Comment: The actual headline element on that page contains `74 Sprüche zum 60. Geburtstag &#8211; für Mama, Papa &#038; Freunde`, so it might be that you have the numeric entity instead of the actual en dash character in your title value there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert an HTML code to your page by Shortcodes you must use `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();` before and after HTML. for example, you can try this code:

```
function show_cat_posts_func( $atts ) {
global $post;

$url_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$url_segments = explode('/', trim($url_path, '/'));
$category_from_url = isset($url_segments[0]) ? $url_segments[0] : '';

$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => $category_from_url, 
), $atts );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => $a['category'],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'post__not_in' => isset($post) ? array($post->ID) : array(),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$output = '';
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    $output .= '<p class="sidebar-heading-txt">' . $a['category'] . '</p>';

    $output .= '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $title = substr($title, 3);
        $title = explode('–', $title)[0];
        $output .= '<li class="sidebar-small-txt"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
} else {
    $output .= '<p>Keine Beiträge in dieser Kategorie gefunden.</p>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();

    ob_start();
    echo $output;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'show_cat_posts', 'show_cat_posts_func' );'
```